# Plugin with id 'io.fabric' not found once generating android project from Ionic

Tags: android, deployment, ionic4, capacitor

I am trying to generate Andriod project from ionic using capacitor but I always get this error:

```
Plugin with id 'io.fabric' not found
```

I did not add any plugin to ionic project. I used only below commands:

```
ng build
ionic capacitor add android
npx cap open android
```

then once andriod studio get opened, I get this error:

```
Plugin with id 'io.fabric' not found
```

Any idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please **show us your build.gradle (app) file**? And what is your **Android Studio version**?

Check if there is any **dependencies** with `io.fabric` and delete the line

```
    dependencies {
            classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:...'
        }
```

Also, in your build.gradle for app module, check if there isn't a line like this and delete it :

```
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```

Are you using Crashlytics?
In your build.gradle files, **delete lines associated to crashlytics or io.fabric**

Comment: i have the same probelm he did, but only after removing every trace of fabric from my build.gradle i started getting the error

Comment: You should delete the folder and create a new one, to be sure